# Postpone execution of Background Service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that when started launches a background service that connects to a RabbitMQ queue, reads any incoming messages and then adds them to a mongodb:

```
public class RabbitLogConsumer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly RabbitMQ.Client.IConnection _connection;
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ChannelType _channelType;
    private readonly ConsumerOptions _consumerOptions;
    private readonly RabbitMqOptions _rabbitMqOptions;
    private readonly LogService _logService;

    public RabbitLogConsumer(IOptions<RabbitMqOptions> options, IOptions<ConsumerOptions> consumerOptions, ILogger<RabbitLogConsumer> logger
        ,LogService logService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _consumerOptions = consumerOptions.Value;
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { Uri = new Uri(options.Value.ConnectionString)};
        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
        _channel.BasicQos(_consumerOptions.PrefetchSize, _consumerOptions.PrefetchCount, false);
        _logService = logService;
        _rabbitMqOptions = options.Value;
        _channelType = ChannelType.Queue;
        DeclareEntity();
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Started Background Task!");
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

        consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Received Message");
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());
                var logRequest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogRequest>(content) ?? throw new Exception("LogRequest was null");
                var serviceLog = new ServiceLog
                {
                    ServiceMessage = logRequest.ServiceMessage,
                    ServiceName = logRequest.ServiceName,
                    CreatedAt = logRequest.Time.ToDateTimeOffset()
                };
                await _logService.AddLog(serviceLog);
                _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Couldn't save log\n {error}", ex);
                _channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false,false);
            }
        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(_consumerOptions.ChannelTarget, false, consumer);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DeclareEntity()
    {
        if (_channelType == ChannelType.Queue)
        {
            DeclareQueue();
        }
        else if (_channelType == ChannelType.Exchange)
        {
            DeclareExchange();
        }
    }

    private void DeclareQueue()
    {
        _channel.QueueDeclarePassive(_consumerOptions.ChannelTarget);
    }

    private void DeclareExchange()
    {
        _channel.ExchangeDeclarePassive(_consumerOptions.ChannelTarget);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I can postpone the initialization of this background service.

I have a healthcheck for both mongo and rabbit

```
public class ConnectionHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
     private readonly ILogger _logger;
     private readonly IOptions<RabbitMqOptions> _options;
     private readonly IOptions<DatabaseSettings> _databaseSettings;

     public ConnectionHealthCheck(IOptions<RabbitMqOptions> options, ILogger<ConnectionHealthCheck> logger)
     {
         _options = options;
         _logger = logger;
     }

     public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         try
         {
             var factory = new ConnectionFactory { Uri = new Uri(_options.Value.ConnectionString) };
             using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
             using var channel = connection.CreateModel();
             channel.QueueDeclarePassive("Notifications");

             if (connection.IsOpen)
             {
                 return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Rabbit connection is working"));
             }

             throw new Exception("Rabbit Connection Health Check Failed");
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("Rabbit Connection Health Check Failed"));
         }
     }
}
```

If a connection cannot be established with rabbit the API will crash, since the error will be inside the constructor of the background service which is going to always start first, which made it difficult to first consult my healthchecks.

What is the cleanest way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Your application will crash/stop if

- The type cannot be created (Exception in the constructor)
- Your ExecuteAsync throws an Exception

What you want to do is probably change your background service to:

- Do nothing in the constructor (bad practice anyway)
- Call the health check service in your background service and start reading as soon as success reported. In case of an read failure, catch the exception
- Start with polling the health check service again and wait until everything is up again